# Debugging multiseat: How to run two X server layouts together without display manager?

Tags: xorg, debugging, display-manager, multiseat

How to run two X servers together, each with its own layout, directly from command line, without any display manager (e.g. GDB, KDM or LightDM)?

Lets say there are two *ServerLayout* sections in *xorg.conf*. One with *Identifier* "seat0", second with "seat1". Then one can run a specific seat for example with one of these commands:

```
$ startx -- -layout seat0
$ startx -- -layout seat1
```

But these commands cannot be executed together! I do not know why but it does not work. (I am also curious what is a problem here?)

The reason why I am trying to leave out a display manager is because of debugging. When multiseat configuration does not work, it is difficult to find out whether there is a problem with a display manager configuration or driver perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for my machine with Debian Wheezy is comprised of two steps:

- On two tty's create an autologin.
- After autologin, automatically start the X with given seat.

I will not post more details because both steps are distro-specific.

Just a few notes:

- Autologin can be done for two distinct users but also for one user.
- For example in Arch, one must start X on terminal where the user is logged, because otherwise the server will fail due to permissions on /dev/tty's. This should be a case from some latest version of X.